# Is the function $x^4+2x^2+2$ limited on the interval $I=(-\infty,0]$ injective and what is it's inverse.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

What I tried:

$$(y^2+1)^2 + 1=x$$
$$\pm\sqrt{\sqrt{x-1}-1}=f^{-1} $$

Is the correct answer positive square root or the negative. I think it's the negative since the interval that was for the domain is now for the range, but I am not sure if it really works this way.

EDIT: ***The inverse of the limited function***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. It should be the negative square root (due to the domain of the original function).

Note that the inner square root is the positive square root too. (Can you see why?)

Comment: Yes, I think it's positive because the outside one has to be also positive, so x needs to be $x\geq2$ for that to work. Because of such value of x it's always going to be positive.

Comment: You got it. Sketching the graph often helps.